# How to change Background color based on time from sunrise to sunset, using jQuery/jQueryUi?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to build in a feature into a weather app I'm making where the background color slowly transitions between light blue and a navyish violet between sunrise and sunset and vice versa. Portions of my code that is relevant code is below, you can check out the whole project here:

http://codepen.io/stephepush/pen/pbWwog

```
var sun = "http://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lon + "&date=today";
  $.getJSON(sun, function(sunData){
    var sunUp = sunData.results.sunrise;
    var sunDown = sunData.results.sunset;
    var sunStatus = sunData.status;
    var nowEpoch = (Date.now())(1000)

      $("body").animate({'background-color':'#56c1ff'},nowEpoch - ((sunDown)*(1000)), 'linear');`
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: What library could I use? What methods? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Your code seems to work more or less. There are a few opportunities and some undefined variables, but it seems ok conceptually.  One thing you will probably need to change is blending from "sunup to sundown" as that in theory blends from twilight to twilight.  Perhaps you should define a mid-day color and incorporate it.

Comment: Thanks @JonSG
I am looking at the project now at 10:21 PM EST, and the color is still bright blue. What I have code-wise doesn't seem to be working, at least for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually this is your code.  We start with the morning color (#fff) and over a period of time we blend to the evening color (#000).

Couple of things though.

Firstly, in your code you are subtracting now from sundown.  You want to do that the other way around.

Secondly, you are blending from one twilight (morning) to a second twilight (evening).  This is likely VERY subtle.  You need a blend to full day in the middle or your background will just look like twilight all day long.

```js
var now = (new Date()).getTime();
var fakeMidnight = now + (30 * 1000);
var untilMidnight = (fakeMidnight - now);

console.log("it will become night over the next : " + (untilMidnight/ 1000) + " seconds.")
$("body").animate({'background-color':'#000'}, (fakeMidnight - now), 'linear')
```

```css
body { background-color:#fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the variable untilMidnight be declared first andthen used in fake midnight? I'm using the Unix Epoch, so If used the current epoch tally for var now and then added midnight*1000, which is the epoch at midnight, wouldn't that just be adding the tally of seconds after 92 years times 1000?

Subtract now from midNight (or fakeMidnight, reverse the equation in until midnight) and then add that number to now and use that number as the time interval of the change?

Comment: **fakeMidnight** is a variable that represents the coming midnight, conceptually **((new Date()).setHours(24,0,0,0))** but that would not make a very lively demo so I set it to 30 seconds in the future.  In your example, this might actually be more like "sundown" as you are using that as the final target time.  **untilMidnight** is the number of ms between **now** and **fakeMidnight**.  This tells your animation how long to blend.  To get it you would subtract **now** from **fakeMidnight**